# MySQL Database value of cell in one table calculated with amount of rows in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two database tables and in one of them i want one of the cells to equal the amount of rows in the other table multiplied by a specific number e.g. 2000.

So for example if there are 10 rows in table 1 i want one of cells in table 2 to be the sum of (2000 x 10).

How can i achieve this?

---

What i am trying to achieve:

What i am trying to do is create a kind of banking database for a virtual company. One of the tables in the database would collect values from a form on a website and then these values would be chucked into this table and would appear as the data for each 'employee' e.g. profits, costs etc.

The second table would total up the 'employees' to create the data for the company as a whole.

E.g.

In the 'employees' table there might be a column called 'fuel cost'.
In the company table there would be a column called 'total fuel cost' which would be equal to the sum of all the employees fuel costs and then this would be displayed on a website.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve automatically updating the values through `triggers` or a procedural SQL (function, stored procedure). Certain RDBMs have agents that will allow you to schedule when the procedure is run.

An example of a trigger in `MySQL` would be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_trig AFTER INSERT ON my_table
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE my_table_total SET total_rows = (SELECT count(*) FROM my_table)*2000;
  END;
```

Comment: Read the tags, the RDBMS is clearly specified. This should also be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I didn't see the tag when I was typing my answer.

Comment: @Danbyization I don't have `PHPmyAdmin`, but I do have `PHPpgAdmin`. When you click on a table it should have tabs at the top and one of them is called `triggers`. However, I recommend running this code from the query tool provided by Php My Admin.

Comment: @enigmasck This may be answering the question but would you use it really? If I inserted, say only 100 rows in `my_table` (which already has, say only the tiny number of 100K rows), how much time do you think the trigger would take (with, lets assume the best here, only 1 row in `my_table_total`)?

Comment: @ypercube I don't know what type of performance the OP is looking for, but programming a simple trigger once and not having to think about it saves more time than having to run an update query every time the OP wants the answer. Say a report with these aggregates is run every day. Think about the time of having to open the query script and run it. Yes, there are wasted cpu cycles for each of these updates, but that is also why I mentioned using a scheduling agent.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to use MySQL as a spreadsheet, and that's really the wrong approach. Simply query `select count(*) from table2` and multiply by 2000 in your application, if that's the result you need.

<strike>My answer is really: "You are asking the wrong question. Rethink what you are trying to do."</strike>

Based on your revised question, I'm saying: Don't keep updating an additional table just to keep an up-to-date summary. There is no need for that. Simply execute something like `select count(*) from detail_table` (perhaps with a `WHERE` condition or somesuch) where you want to see the summary data in your web application.

That's a much, much simpler way to get the required information than maintaining an extra table would be. You should only bother to keep summary tables if the amount of data in your detail tables is so much that running a `COUNT(*)` or similar query every time you need that total would be an overwhelming performance drag.

In other words, *let the database do its job* of sorting and summarizing things.

Comment: I guess i am kind of trying to use it as a spreadsheet. How about i tell you what i want to achieve and then you can tell me the best way to achieve it??

Comment: What makes you think `select employeecount from summary_table` is a better solution than `select count(*) from detail_table`? Either way you're hitting the database, but the latter doesn't force you to maintain redundant data.

Comment: So i should just have the one table for the 'employees' data and for all the totals just calculate them in php script on the webpage and then display them??

Comment: How much of this website do you have working already? I'm asking, because if you know how to `select employeecount from summary_table` (which is basically what you were trying to set up in the first place) then you know how to `select count(*) from detail_table`. Are you able at this point to get *any* SQL data showing up on your website? That's the first thing.

Comment: The whole website is working basically im just adding a few more pages and i've got a fair bit of sql on there already one example is i have an image uploader/slideshow which is where people url's of images and then thats stored in the database and then the image is displayed on the site.

Comment: Now we're going around in circles. In the revised question you give an example of total fuel costs for all employees. Okay. Then why not just query `select sum(fuel_cost) from employees` and be done with it? You already have code that picks up data from that employees table, right?

Comment: Ok i think i understand what your saying now so i'll go off and try to get it working if i have any problems then i'll be back in the next few days lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table and get the row count with the count function:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sum_table ENGINE=MyISAM  ( SELECT SUM(2000 * COUNT(*)) `total` FROM `other_table`);
```

Now you can query sum_table

Comment: But i want it to automatically edit the value as more rows are added to the other table

Comment: You could create `other_table` as a temporary table based on this select statement.

Comment: Or you could put a trigger on `table` to update `other_table`. Personally, I'd just calculate the value on the fly: `SELECT 2000 * COUNT(*) FROM table`.

Comment: What difference as a temporary table to a normal table cus i also want to store other stuff in this table aswell as just this one value

Comment: If you want to store other stuff in the table go with @EdGibbs suggestion and use a trigger.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer: when I say "calculate it on the fly" I mean don't bother having an `other_table` at all - just query up the number whenever you need it. If you'll have very large tables this won't be such a good idea.

Comment: Well the two tables will be smallish to start with but i can see one of them getting bigger quickly so how do i do triggers?

Comment: @Danbyization Can you edit your post and show the columns for each table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand your question. but is this something you want?

```
Update table
    set columnName = SUM(2000 * (select Count(*) from table2))
```